# JRuby with YAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, yaml, syck

When I use Rails with YAML I change boot.rb with

```
require "yaml"
YAML::ENGINE.yamler = "syck"
```

It works fine with normal Ruby.

When I transfer the application from Ruby to JRuby, it doesn't work.

Where should I write these lines in JRuby?

Comment: How does it not work? What error message does it give?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syck is a native gem. a gem that builds native extensions that is. jRuby and native extensions do not mix. Just don't use that syck snippet and your jRuby problem should go away.

Comment: Did you mean "syck", not "suck"?